# Ignore certain voice channel discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot for tracking time spent in voice channels, but I was wondering how I do it does not count the time of the members who are on a certain channel, like a afk channel.

This is the event that i'm using now

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):
    """Monitor status updates for voice channels"""
    s = session()
    # prefer nickname in server to actual discord username
    member_name = before.nick if before.nick else before.name
    try:
        member = s.query(Member).filter(Member.id == before.id).one()
        # update member names on each channel join
        member.name = member_name
    except NoResultFound:
        member = Member(
            id=before.id,
            name=member_name,
            last_join=datetime.datetime.now(),
            total_time=datetime.timedelta(0),
            in_chat=False
        )
        s.add(member)
    if after.voice.voice_channel is None:
        if member.in_chat:
            member.in_chat = False
            member.update_total_time()
        try:
            channel_name = before.voice.voice_channel.name
        except AttributeError:
            channel_name = "Unknown"
        print("{} left voice channel {}.  Total time: {}".format(
            member.name,
            channel_name,
            member.total_time
        ))
    else:
        if member.in_chat:

            if after.voice.is_afk or after.voice.self_deaf or after.voice.deaf:

                member.in_chat = False
                member.update_total_time()
        else:
            member.in_chat = True
            member.last_join = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            channel_name = after.voice.voice_channel.name
        except AttributeError:
            channel_name = "Private"
        print("{} joined voice channel {}.  Total time: {}".format(
            member.name,
            channel_name,
            member.total_time
        ))
    s.commit()
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to track the time? Is it in an event? A command?

Comment: an event, I added in the post

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, you'll be able to check if the voice channel they just joined has a specific ID, supposedly that of an AFK channel:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):
    """Monitor status updates for voice channels"""
    # replace 112233445566778899 with the channel's id you want to ignore
    if after.voice.voice_channel.id != 112233445566778899:
        s = session()
        # rest of your code
```

And if you want to check the ID against multiple, you can compare it to a list:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):
    """Monitor status updates for voice channels"""
    # starting code
    NULL_CHANNELS = [112233445566778899, 998877665544332211]
    if after.voice.voice_channel.id in NULL_CHANNELS:
        s = session()
        # rest of your code
```

---

**References:**

- [`VoiceChannel.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.id)

Comment: still tracking :/

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: @Golps Sorry about the late reply. I just edited the answer - is that looking closer to what you're after?